# Implementing methods on multiple ASPX pages for the same usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization

So, this is my situation. I have multiple ASPX pages (11 total), each of which contains a different set of fields exclusive to those pages.

The way I have implemented is to copy the same code over all those pages, make a few modifications and execute. Ex. on Page 1 remove any handling for Page01 button, on page 2 I remove eventhandler for Page02 button... so on and so forth.

Good News? This works just fine (postbacks, saves, etc). 
Bad News? It is tedious, especially if I have to need to add new event(s) to the control ASCX (TMControl.ASCX). Then, I have to recode all those 11 ASPX pages, wire them to the ASCX, et. al.

Question: Is there a way to do this in a way that I do not duplicate effort?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "...";

    wucTMControls = LoadControl("TMControls.ascx") as TMControls;
    wucTMControls.btnPage02Click += new EventHandler(wucTMControls_btnPage02Click);
    wucTMControls.btnPage03Click += new EventHandler(wucTMControls_btnPage03Click);
    //----------- 
    // similar lines of eventhandling code exists here for pages 4 thru 11, 
    // which I removed for readability
    //----------- 
    wucTMControls.btnSavePageClick += new EventHandler(wucTMControls_btnSavePageClick);
    wucTMControls.btnSavePayeeClick += new EventHandler(wucTMControls_btnSavePayeeClick);
    phTMControls.Controls.Add(wucTMControls);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        loadPage01();
    }
}

void wucTMControls_btnPage02Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (noChangesOnThisPage()) wucTMControls.btnPage02Clicked(); }
void wucTMControls_btnPage03Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (noChangesOnThisPage()) wucTMControls.btnPage03Clicked(); }
//----------- 
// similar lines of eventhandler code exists here for pages 4 thru 11, 
// which I removed for readability
//----------- 
void wucTMControls_btnSavePayeeClick(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UserControl is used when you have to do the same task on different pages. It seems to me that your UserControl does different things on all the pages it is used on. Moreover it has events named like the pages that it is used on. This is really bad design. The UserControl should not have to know anything about the pages. You can use member variables to alter the behavior of the UserControl. But it seems to me that a UserControl is not the solution for your task.

Comment: Indeed, the tasks are the "same" --
-- first allow user to navigate across multiple pages (11) to update details for one entity, the only difference is (which I introduced to the design) is to make disable navigation to the "current" page.
-- allow users to save, reset, cancel, commit (to backend) their changes (obviously, as the page change the values being saved change)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you are right...the user control has no info on what's on the ASPX page. The code on the usercontrol is limited to these few lines!

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sessionID = TMSession.tmCurrentSession.tmSessionPageID;
        }

       // 11 of these... one per page
        protected void btnPage01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (btnPage01Click != null) btnPage01Click(sender, e); }

Comment: Could you provide more information on what your pages and the user control does? I don't understand your concept yet.

Comment: Thanks, sort of --- 

I am not saying that you helped me direclty, but your insistence that I was doing something wrong proded me further to look for a solution.

I had to create custom user control class to resolve my situation. All the events that did the same thing (navigate to a different page) stayed together, the ones that did somewhat different things had to be coded directly on the ASPX page.